# insert image in composition with adobe effect script

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I have a project in Adobe After Effect CC 2015. In a *Placeholder* folder are 100 composition items. Each of these 100 compositions have no layer and are of the size 1100px*1100px (see image below). I have also 100 images named from 1.jpg to 100.jpg of the same size(1100px*1100px).

My goal: **Image x.jpg should be placed as an image layer in composition x with my script**

I would like to write a script for that. I managed to iterate through the 100 compositions with the following code:

```
var placeholder = app.project.item(2);

for(i = 1; i <= placeholder.numItems; i++){
  alert(placeholder.item(i).name);
}
```

Now instead of alerting the name, I would rather like to insert my images to the corresponding layer. I looked in the [After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) and checked the attributes and method list of the `compItem` that I am dealing with (page 52). However, I didn't find a method to add an image to the composition.

Is it not possible or did I overlooked something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found it...

First, one can add a layer like this `element.layers.add(****)`.

I imported the images to the folder as well.

Then the solution was just:

```
var placeholder = app.project.item(2);
var images = app.project.item(102);

for(i = 1; i <= placeholder.numItems; i++){
  placeholder.item(i).layers.add(images.item(i));
}
```